# python version causing problem during Docker build

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, devops

I would like to avoid the following error. what should be the right way to do that. I could try to fix it by using `python2-2.7.18-r0` instead of `2.7.16-r3`. But the question is: will it be the future proof?

```
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  python2-2.7.18-r0:
    breaks: world[python=2.7.16-r3]
ERROR: Service 'frontend' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apk add --no-cache make==4.2.1-r2 python=2.7.16-r3 g++=9.2.0-r4' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:current-alpine as app-builder
ARG NODE_ENV
ENV NODE_ENV ${NODE_ENV}

RUN apk add --no-cache make==4.2.1-r2 python=2.7.16-r3 g++=9.2.0-r4
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile

COPY . .
RUN yarn build
```

Comment: better to add your part of Dockerfile or way to reproduce it

Comment: @Adiii updated the question with dockerfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will it be future proof?

No.  [Python 2 is already end-of-lifed.](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/)  It will not get any bug fixes and security issues will not be addressed.  You should upgrade your application to Python 3, ideally before the Python 2 end-of-life date of 1 January 2020 (four months ago).

In terms of the Dockerfile you show, I'd avoid extremely specific version constraints like you have.  Using the latest version of packages in a specific release of a Linux distribution is usually safe (code tested on Python 2.7.16-r3 will almost certainly run fine on Python 2.7.18-r0).  You might want to pick a more specific distribution in your image's `FROM` line (for example, `FROM node:14-alpine3.11`) to minimize surprises.

Comment: if we fix specific version distribution in docker file, doesn't that mean we are not getting any security update and making dockerfile vulnerable to attack?

Comment: If you target `node:14-alpine-3.11`, and occasionally `docker build --pull`, that tag gets updated to newer versions of Node 14.x (right now it is 14.2.0), so you will get updates.